# OS X - x64: stack not 16 byte aligned error

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64

I know that OS X is 16 byte stack align, but I don't really understand why it is causing an error here.

**All I am doing here is to pass an object size (which is 24) to %rdi, and call malloc. Does this error mean I have to ask for 32 bytes ?**

And the error message is:

> libdyld.dylib`stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error:
>   ->  0x7fffc12da2fa <+0>: movdqa %xmm0, (%rsp)
>       0x7fffc12da2ff <+5>: int3
>
> libdyld.dylib`_dyld_func_lookup:
>       0x7fffc12da300 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
>       0x7fffc12da301 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp

Here is the code:

```
Object_copy:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rbp, %rsp

    subq $8, %rsp
    movq %rdi, 8(%rsp)          # save self address
    movq obj_size(%rdi), %rax   # get object size
    imul $8, %rax          
    movq %rax, %rdi 
    callq _malloc             <------------------- error in this call

    # rsi old object address
    # rax new object address
    # rdi object size, mutiple of 8

    # rcx temp reg

    # copy object tag
    movq 0(%rsi), %rcx
    movq %rcx, 0(%rax)

    # set rdx to counter, starting from 8
    movq $8, %rdx

    # add 8 to object size, since we are starting from 8
    addq $8, %rdi

    start_loop:
        cmpq %rdx, %rdi
        jle end_loop

        movq (%rdx, %rsi, 1), %rcx
        movq %rcx, (%rdx, %rax, 1)

        addq $8, %rdx
        jmp start_loop

    end_loop:
        leave 
        ret



Main_protoObj:
    .quad    5                          ; object tag
    .quad    3                          ; object size
    .quad    Main_dispatch_table        ; dispatch table

_main:
    leaq Main_protoObj(%rip), %rdi
    callq Object_copy                # copy main proto object
    subq $8, %rsp                    # save the main object on the stack
    movq %rax, 8(%rsp)
    movq %rax, %rdi                 # set rdi point to SELF
    callq Main_init
    callq Main_main

    addq $8, %rsp                    # restore stack

    leaq _term_msg(%rip), %rax
    callq _print_string
```

Comment: At the point just before a _CALL_ is made in 64-bit code _RSP_ must be evenly divisible by 16. When the return address is put on the stack and transfer controlled to the routine the stack becomes misaligned by 8 bytes (return value on stack now). `pushq %rbp` places an additional 8 bytes on stack so stack is now aligned back to 16-byte boundary. You then do `subq $8, %rsp` which means _RSP_ is now misaligned by 8 again. Then you call `malloc` with misaligned stack. Rather than `subq $8, %rsp` try `subq $16, %rsp` to keep 16-byte alignment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Hey Michael, thanks so much for your answer, it really helped me out. Do you mind posting your comment in the form of an actual answer so that its more obvious how to address this issue for other people stumbling on this question? I can do it if you don't want to :)

Comment: You can take what you have discovered and self answer your question if you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said, MacOS X has a 16 byte stack alignment, which means that the machine expects each variable on the stack to start on a byte that is a multiple of 16 from the current stack pointer.

When the stack is misaligned, it means we start trying to read variables from the middle of that 16 byte window and usually end up with a segmentation fault.

Before you call a routine in your code, you need to make sure that your stack is aligned correctly; in this case, meaning that the base pointer register is divisible by 16.

```
subq $8, %rsp               # stack is misaligned by 8 bytes
movq %rdi, 8(%rsp)          #
movq obj_size(%rdi), %rax   #
imul $8, %rax               #
movq %rax, %rdi             #
callq _malloc               # stack is still misaligned when this is called
```

To fix this, you can `subq` the `%rsp` by something like 16 instead of 8.

```
subq $16, %rsp               # stack is still aligned
movq %rdi, 16(%rsp)          #
...                          #
callq _malloc                # stack is still aligned when this is called, good
```

Comment: *which means that the compiler expects each variable to be defined within a 16 byte slot of memory*.  No, that's not what it means.  The width of arg slots on the stack is 8, but the *first* one is at a 16-byte aligned address.  But yes, the `push %rbp` in the function prologue aligned the stack by 16, so subtracting a multiple of 16 when reserving stack space is necessary.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah I see, thanks for the correction! Is there anything else wrong or that I should add here?

Comment: *meaning that the base pointer register is divisible by 16.*  Alignment of `rbp` has nothing to do with anything; the ABI doesn't specify anything about how RBP is used.  RBP is 16-byte aligned in the OP's broken code because it's always set to `rsp_on_entry-8` when you make a traditional stack frame, so that's obviously not a sufficient condition.  Also, your first paragraph is still wrong.  The first arg starts at a 16-byte aligned address, but later args (if any) are only 8-byte aligned unless that specific arg has a higher alignment requirement (e.g. `long double`, or `__m128`).